Gradle build can't find dependencies while the first run
I have an android project with such structure:
App
  settings.gradle
  library
    library
    library1
    library2

library depends on library1 and library2.
App settings.gradle is:
....
include ':library-library1'
include ':library-library2'
include ':library-library'
....

library build.gradle looks like this:
android{
....
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':library-library1')
    implementation project(':library-library2')
}

library Android.mk file:
....
LOCAL_MODULE    := library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := library.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../library1/include \
           $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../library2/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS := \
  -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../library1/build/intermediates/library_jni/$(BUILD_TYPE)/jni/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI) \
    -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../library2/build/intermediates/library_jni/$(BUILD_TYPE)/jni/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI) \
  -llog -landroid -llibrary1 -llibrary2
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
....

The problem is that build fails on the first run with errors:
"error: cannot find -llibrary1"
"error: cannot find -llibrary2"

And I see that Android Studio creates .so files for both library1 and library2 after first build run. On the second and other runs everything is OK. So it looks like wrong build order - library builds before it's dependencies.
What is the proper way to specify a dependencies for the library?

You appear to be using incorrect notation.
To include a subproject located in the folder ./library/library1 relative to the root project, use:
include 'library:library1'

in your settings.gradle file (documentation). Here, the leading colon is optional, so you could also write :library:library1 which is the full project path.
To include that project as an implementation dependency in another project, use:
dependencies {
    implementation project(':library:library1')
}

in the dependent project's build.gradle file. Here, the leading colon is not optional.

There are another dependencies in the project which are included with - as well (like ":library-") - and it works. Anyway, I tried to use : instead - the same errors
